# Отображение панели управления bitrix

Tags: linux, windows, битрикс, cms, администрирование

Установил bitrix:Управление сайтом (Бизнес). После установки и нажатия кнопки Перейти на сайт получил окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно отобразить панель управления битриксом?

Answer (score 0):

По каким-то причинам небольшой блок панели управления на front-end не виден. Он может быть скрыт стилями, какими конкретно – надо смотреть подробно ваш сайт.

Для отображения панели управления на front-end нужно вставить (и обычно уже скорей всего вставлено) в код шаблона после тега

```
<div id="panel"><? $APPLICATION->ShowPanel();?></div>
```

Чтобы просто попасть в админку, введите в адресную строку браузера адрес [http://ваш_сайт.ру/bitrix/](http://%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83/bitrix/)